# Can we exclude row from filtering - YADCF Plugin

Tags: yadcf

Is there any possibility for excluding the row from filter.
Suppose i have 20 `<tr>` i want 1, 6, 11 or any number row will not be effected by the filtering. It will be always visible. 
Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [html5-data-attributes](https://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html) along with yadcf [html5_data](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/b2cffd555b0fb8180c58600b49985e39ed335916/dist/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L111) , you can try omit the `data-filter` from certain rows

> - html5_data -
>                 Required:           false
>                 Type:               String
>                 Default value:      undefined
>                 Possible values:    data-filter / data-search / anything that is supported by datatables
>                 Description:        Allows to filter based on data-filter / data-search attributes of the  element, read more: http://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html

Comment: I'm trying to follow your response.  In the createdCell function, I conditionally remove or populate the 'data-filter' attribute: `$(td).removeAttr("data-filter");` or `$(td).attr("data-filter", cellData);` and then use the html5_data tag in the yadcf filter settings: `html5_data: "data-filter"` but it doesn't seem to only apply to rows with data-filter attribute.

Comment: please post a link to a test page (jsfiddle)

Comment: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ty5s079/4) - note, the goal is for the "Not filter" row to always show and not be filtered by the date range.  It may be filtered by other filters however (note the range number filter).

Comment: I'll also add that I keep getting `Cannot read property '@data-filter' of null` when I add `"html5_data": "data-filter"` in the filter definition.

Comment: Just as an update, I no longer am using this approach.  However, I would like to see a working example where using `html5_data` in yadcf can omit rows without a `data-filter` attribute.

Comment: @evv_gis , please open an issue on yadcf github repo, otherwise, I'm afraid I will forget about it (very busy right now)